# Hacer un join con tabla externa he interna Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

es la primera vez que trabajo con tablas internas y externas. Estoy guardando datos desde una APP a una base de datos externa de otra app. Me funciona todo bien pero necesito hacer un join de la tabla externa con la interna.

**Modelo de la tabla externa**

```
class NoticiaDepildiodo extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'depildiodo';
    protected $table = 'noticias';
    protected $primaryKey='id';
}
```

**Intento de JOIN con la misma conexión y la propia de la app**

```
$noticias = NoticiaDepildiodo::leftjoin('categoria_blogs', 'noticias.id_categoria', '=', 'categoria_blogs.id')
           ->leftjoin('users', 'noticias.id_usuario', '=', 'users.id')
           ->select('noticias.*', 'users.name AS nombreRedactor', 'categoria_blogs.valor')->get();
```

Pero el campo `nombreRedactor` me lo devuelve `null`

```
#original: array:13 [▼
        "id" => 3
        "foto" => "/storage/photos/1/Blog/noticia.jpg"
        "titulo" => "Láser Alejandrita + Diodo"
        "subtitulo" => "Novedoso sistema de depilación láser Alejandrita + Diodo"
        "cuerpo" => """
          cuerpo de la noticia
          """
        "id_usuario" => 2
        "id_categoria" => 1
        "fecha" => "2019-06-14"
        "estado" => 2
        "created_at" => "2020-12-05 17:54:37"
        "updated_at" => "2020-12-05 17:54:37"
        "nombreRedactor" => null
        "valor" => "Consejo"
      ]
```

Comment: Prueba usar el método `select` y en el indicar exactamente que columnas deseas recuperar.

Comment: Pero eso ya lo estoy haciendo @BetaM aquí `->select('noticias.*', 'users.name AS nombreRedactor', 'categoria_blogs.valor')->get();` no?

Comment: Si pero no indicas de que base de datos vienen

Comment: ah pues ahí me pillas @BetaM como hago para indicarle la base da datos??

Comment: No encuentro como hacer lo que me dices @BetaM